# How do I allow the user to select data from a combo box in a Query

Tags: combobox

I have a database which lists students who have went on exchanges from 1986 onwards to about 30 institutions.  I have set up the file  as follows:

File name: 1986 onwards
Table: Incoming Students
Field: Institution

I set up the query with the following parameter: [Enter Institution] - the problem is the institution can be spelt in various ways or displayed in various ways ie Malta University versus University of Malta.  When the user enters the data into the form they select from a drop down box.

How can I set up my query so the user can also select from the drop down box or even enter part of the title of the University ie Enter 'Kyoto' instead of the full title of 'Kyoto University'.

My boss thinks after two 3 hour database classes I should be able to do this - I have searched high and low and cannot find anything which I understand.

Comment: I'm guessing this is Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 0):

Make a form with your dropdown box on it.  In the query, instead of saying `[Enter Institution]`, say `Forms!MyForm!MyDropdown`.

That's not the whole story, but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I am so screwed with this, and to say my boss is on my back is an understatement!!!

I entered the following:
[Forms]![Incoming_Students]![Institution:]

I have the FORM designed and it is called Incoming_Students and the FIELD with the drop down box is called Insitution:

When I entered this criteria it just changed the ext from 
Enter Institution === to ==== Forms!Incoming_Students!Institution: === it did not give the user the option to select from the drop down box.